# Difference between "per month" and "monthly"

Tags: time

I've referred [Is there any difference between “monthly average” and “average per month”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/210018/is-there-any-difference-between-monthly-average-and-average-per-month)

But I want more clearer answer **most difference** of it.

- **Per Month** - I've to pay $100 ***per month***  as wages.
- **Monthly** -  I've to pay $100 ***monthly*** as wages.

**My understanding**:
- **Per Month**   - I've to pay on each month.
- **Monthly** -  I've to pay once in a month.

Seems no much difference but which once is preferable in that context?

Comment: In these sentences I would say "I have to pay", not "I've to pay". Yes, *I've* is an abbreviation of *I have*, but it doesn't sound right when used before *to*. "I've got to pay" sounds fine though.

Comment: Thanks for the attention. I will remember it.

Comment: It's possible you could say "the fee is $20 per month, paid quarterly." (i.e. you pay for 3 months at a time.) Although maybe you could get away with using "monthly" in that, it would be more confusing.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the difference is, or which variant would be more common in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both indicate a recurring period.

The phrase “per month” can be used to apply intervals within a period, i.e. twice per month.

While “monthly”, denotes a specific period. You may say “twice monthly”, but you may prefer to say, “biweekly”.

In the OP context I would recommend “$100 per month”.

Comment: Thanks, I understand when to use, it must fit into that context. It'd be odd while I'd say **It would affect my per month budget**

Answer (score 1):

Saying that somebody has to pay a certain amount per month (or per hour, per day, per week, etc.) does not imply anything as to when and how frequently the payments are to be made. The only information that such a formulation conveys is how the total amount of the payment, whenever it is made, is related to the period of time **for** which it is made. A payment made for a certain period need not be made within that period.

The most obvious way to see this is to consider that nobody who is told that his wages will be £__ per hour expects to receive a payment of the wages every hour.

*Monthly* (or *weekly*, *quarterly*, etc.) can in such contexts mean the same as *per month*, but it can also mean that the payments themselves are made once a month (or week, quarter, etc.). *Monthly fee*, for example, will likely be understood in the first way, and *monthly pay cheque* in the latter, while the OP's 'I've to pay $100 monthly' is ambiguous between the two.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out ambiguity. That I was confused I wanted to create an option in my software defininig wages of labors. wages per month or monthly wages. Like per annum or yearly. That I was confused about month.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Or you can consider I'm telling my expenses. My expenses is $100 per month/monthly on account of wages.